# Fibonacci proof by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have fibonacci numbers defined as such:

$$
 f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$$with$$    f(0) = 0 $$$$f(1) = 1$$

I have to prove that $$ F(n) \geq 1.5^{n-1}, n \geq 6$$

**Base Case:**

$$
f(6) = 8 \geq (1.5)^5 = 7.6
$$ 
Base holds

**Inductive hypothesis**
$$
 k \geq 6
$$$$
f(k) \geq (1.5)^{k-1}
$$

**Inductive Step**

Here is how I have started, any hints or pointers on how to continue are appreciated

$$
f(k-1) \geq (1.5)^{k+1-1}$$
$$
f(k) + f(k-1) = (1.5)^{k-1} + (1.5)^{k-2}$$
now I think where I want to go from here is to expand the right side of this equation out, but I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: The base case should include $f(7)=13$, then you can apply the recursion. Just remember $2.5\gt2.25$.

Comment: Hint: $1.5 + 1 \ge 1.5^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually easier to use two base cases (corresponding to $n = 6,7$), and then use the previous two results to induct: Notice that if both $$f(k - 1) \ge (1.5)^{ k - 2}$$
and $$f(k) \ge (1.5)^{k - 1}$$

then we have

\begin{align*}
f(k+1) &= f(k) + f(k - 1) \\
&\ge (1.5)^{k - 1} + (1.5)^{k - 2} \\
&= (1.5)^{k - 2}\Big(1.5 + 1\Big) \\
&> (1.5)^{k - 2} \cdot (1.5)^2
\end{align*}
since $1.5^2 = 2.25 < 2.5$.

Comment: Thanks! Now it seems so obvious!